# Choosing an intercept in lmer

Tags: lme4, mixed-models, intercept, coefficients

I am using an lmer model (from lmerTest) to understand whether size is significantly correlated with gene expression, and if so, which specific genes are correlated with size (also accounting for 'female' and 'cage' as random effects):

```
lmer(Expression ~ size*genes + (1|female) + (1|cage), data = df)
```

In the summary output, one of my genes is being used up as an intercept (since it is highest in the alphabet, 'ctsk'). After reading around, it was recommended that I choose the highest (or lowest) expressed gene as my intercept to compare everything else against. In this case, the gene 'star' was the highest expressed. After re-levelling my data, and re-running the model with 'star' as the intercept, ALL the other slopes are now significant in summary() output, although anova() output is identical.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to not have one of my genes used as an intercept? If it is not possible, then how do I know which gene I should choose as an intercept?
2. Can I test whether the slopes are different from zero? Perhaps this is where I would specify no intercept in my model (i.e. '0+size*genes')?
3. Is it possible to have the intercept as the mean of all slopes?

I will then use lsmeans to determine whether the slopes are significantly different from each other.

Here is some reproducible code:

```
df <- structure(list(size = c(13.458, 13.916, 13.356, 13.84, 14.15, 
                          16.4, 15.528, 13.916, 13.458, 13.285, 15.415, 14.181, 13.367, 
                          13.356, 13.947, 14.615, 15.804, 15.528, 16.811, 14.677, 13.2, 
                          17.57, 13.947, 14.15, 16.833, 13.2, 17.254, 16.4, 14.181, 13.367, 
                          14.294, 13.84, 16.833, 17.083, 15.847, 13.399, 14.15, 15.47, 
                          13.356, 14.615, 15.415, 15.596, 15.847, 16.833, 13.285, 15.47, 
                          15.596, 14.181, 13.356, 14.294, 15.415, 15.363, 15.4, 12.851, 
                          17.254, 13.285, 17.57, 14.7, 17.57, 13.947, 16.811, 15.4, 13.399, 
                          14.22, 13.285, 14.344, 17.083, 15.363, 14.677, 15.945), female = structure(c(7L, 
                                                                                                       12L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                                                                       11L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 
                                                                                                       8L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                                                                       10L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 
                                                                                                       11L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 9L), .Label = c("2", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "3", "6", "10", "11", "16", "18", "24", "25", "28", "30", "31", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "116", "119", "128", "135", "150", "180", "182", "184", "191", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "194", "308", "311", "313", "315", "320", "321", "322", "324", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "325", "329", "339", "342"), class = "factor"), Expression = c(1.10620339407889, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.06152707257767, 2.03000185674761, 1.92971750056866, 1.30833983462599, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.02760836165184, 0.960969703469363, 1.54706275342441, 0.314774666283256, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.63330873720495, 0.895123048920455, 0.917716470037954, 1.3178821021651, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.57879156856332, 0.633429011784367, 1.12641940390116, 1.0117475796626, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.687813581350802, 0.923485880847423, 2.98926377892241, 0.547685277701021, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.967691178046748, 2.04562285257417, 1.09072264997544, 1.57682235413366, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.967061529758701, 0.941995966023426, 0.299517719292817, 1.8654758451133, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.651369936708288, 1, 1.04407979584122, 0.799275069735012, 1.007255409328, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.428129727802404, 0.93927930755046, 0.987394257033815, 0.965050972503591, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.06719308587322, 1.63846508102874, 0.997380526962644, 0.60270197593643, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.78682867333149, 0.552922632281237, 3.06702198884562, 0.890708510580522, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.15168812515828, 0.929205084743164, 2.27254101826041, 1, 0.958147442333527, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.05924173014089, 0.984356852670054, 0.623630720815415, 0.796864961771971, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.4679841984147, 1.07248904053777, 1.79630829771291, 0.929642913565982, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.296954006040077, 2.25741254504115, 1.17188536743493, 0.849778293699644, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.32679163466857, 0.598119006609413, 0.975660099975423, 1.01494421228949, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.14007557533352, 2.03638316428189, 0.777347547080068), cage = structure(c(64L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       49L, 56L, 66L, 68L, 48L, 53L, 49L, 64L, 56L, 55L, 68L, 80L, 56L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       64L, 75L, 69L, 53L, 59L, 66L, 63L, 59L, 64L, 68L, 59L, 63L, 50L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       48L, 68L, 80L, 49L, 66L, 59L, 50L, 48L, 63L, 68L, 62L, 56L, 75L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       55L, 81L, 48L, 59L, 56L, 62L, 81L, 68L, 56L, 49L, 55L, 62L, 55L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       63L, 50L, 56L, 59L, 75L, 59L, 64L, 59L, 55L, 63L, 66L, 56L, 53L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       50L, 62L, 66L, 81L), .Label = c("023", "024", "041", "042", "043", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "044", "044 bis", "045", "046", "047", "049", "051", "053", "058", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "060", "061", "068", "070", "071", "111", "112", "113", "123", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "126", "128", "14", "15", "23 bis", "24", "39", "41", "42", "44", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "46 bis", "47", "49", "51", "53", "58", "60", "61", "67", "68", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "70", "75", "76", "9", "D520", "D521", "D522", "D526", "D526bis", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D533", "D535", "D539", "D544", "D545", "D545bis", "D546", "D561", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "D561bis", "D564", "D570", "D581", "D584", "D586", "L611", "L616", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "L633", "L634", "L635", "L635bis", "L637", "L659", "L673", "L676", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "L686", "L717", "L718", "L720", "L725", "L727", "L727bis"), class = "factor"), 
                 genes = c("igf1", "gr", "ctsk", "ets2", "ctsk", "mtor", "igf1", 
                           "sgk1", "sgk1", "ghr1", "ghr1", "gr", "ctsk", "ets2", "timp2", 
                           "timp2", "ets2", "rictor", "sparc", "mmp9", "gr", "sparc", 
                           "mmp2", "ghr1", "mmp9", "sparc", "mmp2", "timp2", "star", 
                           "sgk1", "mmp2", "gr", "mmp2", "rictor", "timp2", "mmp2", 
                           "mmp2", "mmp2", "mmp2", "rictor", "mtor", "ghr1", "star", 
                           "igf1", "mmp9", "igf1", "igf2", "rictor", "rictor", "mmp9", 
                           "ets2", "ctsk", "mtor", "ghr1", "mtor", "ets2", "ets2", "igf2", 
                           "igf1", "sgk1", "sgk1", "ghr1", "sgk1", "igf2", "star", "mtor", 
                           "igf2", "ghr1", "mmp2", "rictor")), .Names = c("size", "female", 
                                                                          "Expression", "cage", "genes"), row.names = c(1684L, 2674L, 10350L, 
                                                                                                                        11338L, 10379L, 4586L, 1679L, 3637L, 3610L, 5537L, 5530L, 2676L, 
                                                                                                                        10355L, 11313L, 8422L, 8450L, 11322L, 6494L, 9406L, 13262L, 2653L, 
                                                                                                                        9407L, 12274L, 5564L, 13256L, 9394L, 12294L, 8438L, 750L, 3614L, 
                                                                                                                        12303L, 2671L, 12293L, 6513L, 8437L, 12284L, 12305L, 12267L, 
                                                                                                                        12276L, 6524L, 4567L, 5545L, 733L, 1700L, 13241L, 1674L, 7471L, 
                                                                                                                        6528L, 6498L, 13266L, 11308L, 10347L, 4566L, 5541L, 4590L, 11315L, 
                                                                                                                        11333L, 7482L, 1703L, 3607L, 3628L, 5529L, 3617L, 7483L, 722L, 
                                                                                                                        4565L, 7476L, 5532L, 12299L, 6510L), class = "data.frame")

genes <- as.factor(df$genes)
library(lmerTest)

fit1 <- lmer(Expression ~ size * genes +(1|female) + (1|cage), data = df) 
anova(fit1)
summary(fit1) # uses the gene 'ctsk' for intercept, so re-level to see what    happens if I re-order based on highest value (sgk1):
df$genes <- relevel(genes, "star")

# re-fit the model with 'star' as the intercept:
fit1 <- lmer(Expression ~ size * genes +(1|female) + (1|cage), data = df)
anova(fit1) # no difference here
summary(fit1) # lots of difference
```

My sample data is pretty long since the model wouldn't run otherwise-hopefully this is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to interpret the coefficients in your fitted model, that isn't the most fruitful or productive approach. Instead, just fit the model using whatever contrast methods are used by default, and follow-up with suitable post-hoc analyses.

For that, I suggest using the **emmeans** (estimated marginal means) package, which is a continuation of **lsmeans** where all future developments will take place. The package has several vignettes, and the one most relebant to your situation is `vignette("interactions")`, which you may view [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) -- particularly the section on interactions with covariates.

Briefly, comparing intercepts can be very misleading, since those are predictions at `size = 0` which is an extrapolation; and moreover, as you suggest in a question, the real point here is probably to compare slopes more than intercepts. For that purpose, there is an `emtrends()` function (or, if you like, its alias `lstrends()`).

I also strongly recommend displaying a graph of the model predictions so you can visualize what's going on. This may be done via

```
library(emmeans)
emmip(fit1, gene ~ size, at = list(size = range(df$size)))
```

Comment: I went through the vignette that you attached but I can't seem to get the section on interactions with covariates working with my data... I can see the pairwise comparisons of the slopes as well as the plot, which works nicely-thank you. Is there a way to get the interactions with covariates working with my data? And can I get the overall p-value for which gene is significantly correlated with size (i.e., not how significant they are the each other)? Perhaps this isn't even possible.

Comment: I guess I don’t understand your question. When a factor interacts with a covariate, that means the slopes are different. And you have indicated that you have a good plot and a comparison of slopes; so it seems like you have already done what’s needed.

Comment: You can use `car::Anova()` to get an overall test of the interaction effect; and the individual t tests of the `test(emtrends(...))` result gives you an idea of which slopes differ from zero, indicating which correlations are strongest.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much @rvl

Comment: I just want to make sure that the    test(emtrends(...))    actually compares the slopes to zero, and not the mean of all slopes?

Comment: Yes — as documented. You can specify `null` to rest against a different value. To test against their average you need `contrast(emtrends(...), “eff”)`

Comment: perhaps I need to post a separate question for this one, but is there a way of adapting the above code to be able to compare the slopes from polynomial models?